# UiSplitViewController App without storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I am new to iOS development and need a bit of help. I have searched high and low and cannot find the answer. It's more like I don't understand what is happening. My issue is, I am trying to code a Master-Detail App without using storyboards. This helps me get a better understanding of how ViewControllers are managed and handled. I am trying to present the DetailViewController after an item is selected in a tableView in the MasterViewController on iPhone. On iPad it works well because both views are side by side.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //Pass data to detailViewController
    if ([_detailDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(item:selectedAtIndexPath:)]) {

            [_detailDelegate item:[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] findItemAtIndex:indexPath.row] selectedAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone ) {

        // show DetailViewController


        NSArray *viewControllers = self.splitViewController.viewControllers;

        UINavigationController *detailNavigationViewController = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];

        [self showDetailViewController:detailNavigationViewController sender:nil];

    }


}
```

In a storyboard the selected ViewCell has a `show detail segue` to the detailViewController. How can I achieve the same thing without using storyboards?

My AppDelegate code for a better picture

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

UISplitViewController *splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];

self.window.rootViewController = splitViewController;


UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];


MasterTableViewController *masterTableViewController = [[MasterTableViewController alloc] init];
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];

masterTableViewController.detailDelegate = detailViewController;
detailViewController.masterDelegate = masterTableViewController;


masterNavigationController.viewControllers = @[masterTableViewController];
detailNavigationController.viewControllers = @[detailViewController];

[splitViewController setViewControllers:@[masterNavigationController,detailNavigationController]];


[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this issue after reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25359131/ios-split-view-controller-how-do-i-get-a-pointer-reference-to-the-detail-v). When the UISplitViewController detects that it is in portrait mode on an iPhone it removes the DetailViewController from its `viewControllers property`. When it is in landscape mode its add the DetailViewController(Secondary Controller)back to the viewControllers property.

Solution:

Added a strong reference property in the MasterViewController(Primary Controller) to store the DetailViewController.

When an item is selected in the MasterViewController table, I checked the UISplitViewController viewControllers property and if the DetailViewController was missing from the Array, I pushed the DetailViewController onto the Parent Controller(UINavigationViewController)stack.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

DetailViewController *detailController = (DetailViewController *) self.detailViewController.viewControllers[0];

[detailController item:[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] findItemAtIndex:indexPath.row] selectedAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if (self.splitViewController.viewControllers.count == 1) {

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing:

```
    [self showDetailViewController:detailNavigationViewController sender:nil];
```

to:

```
    [self.splitViewController showDetailViewController:detailNavigationViewController sender:nil];
```